# Multiple Commands in If Statement?

Tags: php, if-statement, command

I'm fairly new to PHP so I was wondering whether or not you could have to 'commands' in an if statement, like:

```
$value = 1;
$values = 2;

if ($value == '1' & $values == '2') {
 do something
} else {
 do something else
}
```

Would that work? I probably have the syntax wrong however you get the gist. Haha
Thanks for the help.

Comment: To express and `and` condition you need two `&`: `if ($value == '1' && $values == '2')`, anyway yes it is possible, you can have as many conditions as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are new to use conditional operators read first before implement.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

```
$value = 1;
$values = 2;

if ($value == '1' && $values == '2') {
// do something
} else {
// do something else
}
```